# Counting from 0 to 15

Tags: lua

I am making something in **lua** and I need to count from *0 to 15*

I know I can do

```
for I = 0,15 do
  print(I)
end
```

However I need to do it in a loop

I tried

```
 local I = 1,15
```

But that just makes `I` 1

Any help?

Comment: You want to print 1-15? or you want sum?

Comment: I want to print 0-15

Comment: *I need to do it in a loop.* Well, `for` loop is a type of loop.

Comment: Yes but in a never ending loop

Comment: What *never ending loop*? It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this (based on a comment)

```
I = 0
while true do
  -- do something with I
  if I==15 then I=0 else I=I+1 end
end
```

The last line in the loop can be written as `I = (I+1) % 16`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=0
while( a < 16 )
do
   print("value of a:", a)
   a = a+1
end
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: I need to have that in a while true do loop though

Comment: Okay I'll try that, basically what I'm doing is using computer craft a mod for minecraft that allows lua in game to set a block of wool with the metadata of that wool going from 0 to 15 then looping back to 0 so on so forth

Answer (score 0):

You want the 'mod' operator `%`.
It returns the remainder of a division; this will give you the 'wrap around' behaviour you're after:

```
local i = 0
while true do
    print(i)
    i = (i + 1) % 15
end
```